# Problem parsing XML using Jquery (IE9)

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, internet-explorer-9, using

ok ...

so I got this XML file and I need to parse it ....

```
<Current> 
    <Artists>
         <![CDATA[ Artists of movie ]]>
     </Artists> 
     <Title>
         <![CDATA[ title of movie ]]>
     </Title> 
    <Image/>
    <Purchase/>
</Current>
```

...... // keeps on going in this manner ....

and here is my code ....

```
$(document).ready
(

function()
{ 

 $.get("url of xml file ",{}, 
    function(xml)
     {
         $("Current", xml).each
         (
            function(i)
                {
                    author= $(this).find("Authors").text();
                     alert(author);
                }
         );
    }
    );
});
```

why is it not working?  Please note that this code is in IE9 ...  :( I hope its not the browser :(

Comment: * OOPS - Notice above I did a mistake the tag Authors in the Javascript code should read Artists.  Many thanks and apologies....

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap the  tag into another container. you can't select the root of the document.

```
<List>
    <Current> 
        <Artists>
            <![CDATA[ Artists of movie ]]>
        </Artists> 
        <Title>
           <![CDATA[ title of movie ]]>
        </Title> 
       <Image/>
       <Purchase/> 
   </Current>
</List>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVeb5/19/)